# Javascript close modal of another window

Tags: javascript, window, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to close another window modal?

```
var ws=window.open('/Views/View2','View two');

$(ws.document.getElementById('IdleEnd')).modal('hide')//not executing
```

I changed the html of other window modal, but unable to close

```
$(ws.document.getElementById('IdleEnd')).html('new content');
```

Comment: I bet jQuery needs to be called in that other window, rather than on the original page. `ws.$(...`

Comment: *pays the dept* please post as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet jQuery `.modal` only works when the `$` being used is on the same window that the `.modal` is being called on. Assuming the other window has jQuery as well, try:

```
ws.$('#IdleEnd').modal('hide');
```